# Injecting CKEditor dynamically error Angular

Tags: angular, ckeditor

Hi I want to integrate my custom version of CKEditor (built using CKEditor online builder) in my angular project. So here what I did:

1. 1- I copied the CKEditor folder in the assets/js/
2. I created two
   scripts objects in my **ngAfterViewInit** function;one to include the ckeditor.js file in my component and the second to specify the objects that should be edited by ckeditor as following:

   ```
       ngAfterViewInit(): void {

       let s = document.createElement("script");
       s.type = "text/javascript";
       s.src = "assets/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js";
       this.ckeditorscript = document.createElement("script");
       this.ckeditorscript.id = "ckeditorscript";
       this.ckeditorscript.type = "text/javascript";

       this.ckeditorscript.innerHTML = `
         CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline=true;
         CKEDITOR.inline('mydiv');
      `;
       this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
       this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(this.ckeditorscript);

     }
   ```

   the first script is working fine (ckeditor is being added to components editablecontent) but the second script is causing me this problem:

   ```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:15
   ```

Comment: define CKEDITOR, what is a constructor?

Comment: Do you import CKEDITOR in app.module.ts? You can add CKEDITOR ng2 with https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor

Comment: @RomanC I think that CKEDITOR should not be defined in the constructor because I am not calling it directly in my typescript file but via the second script that I am injecting in my component template, the definition of ckeditor supposed to be done automatically with the first script injection

Comment: @Pterrat I don't want to use the ng-ckeditor because it  doesn't support  the inline editing https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor/issues/5 also I want to use my custom CKEditor that I have built using the CKEditor online builder (I added some plugins and a custom theme ..)

Comment: @radtelbi You can edit the basic CKEDITOR component and pull request on github repository then community will love you :)